# VSTS Pipeline Variables: URL replacement parameter

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

New to VSTS and the whole build process in general. How, when declaring a URL as variable in your pipeline do you specify the replacement parameters for the call? In Octopus Iv just use ={0}.

Example
"http://something.com/Country/all?country={0}"

In VSTS is it the same?

Comment: What the `{0}` mean? when you replace it?